# Weird code collapse points in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Can only collapse seemingly random methods, bit annoying why is this?

[image: dfuq bruh]

Comment: Try restarting eclipse with a "-clean" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting your project(s) in Project Explorer and hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> (refresh). Then in the Project menu, select "Clean..." and hit OK. That should hopefully refresh all your markers.

If that doesn't work, Sandeep suggested restarting Eclipse with the `-clean` command line parameter.

Comment: -clean did it. props to sandeep as well :)

Comment: Sweet, glad that worked. Working with multiple git branches, I find I have to refresh and do a clean build most of the time when I switch branches. Those two steps will often clear up a lot of random problems for me.